# Inno setup cannot launch exe

Tags: vb.net, vba, inno-setup

I have created windows vb application running on 32bit machine and packaged through Inno Setup Compiler 5.4.2.  Once i install the application in the machine successfully, it doesn't launch the application and log file shows all dependencies are installed successfully.

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?
Please go through the Inno script

```
[Setup] 
AppId={{32558ED7-C211-4AB1-9D3F-9F36F214531E}
AppName=MyApplication
AppVerName=MyApplication 
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApplication
DefaultGroupName=MyApplication
LicenseFile=F:\README.TXT
OutputDir=F:\setUp
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked


[Files]
Source: "MyApp4.0.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "XXX.DLL"; DestDir: "{app}\components"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "App.ocx"; DestDir: "{app}\components"; Flags: regserver restartreplace sharedfile 
Source: "MSCOMCTL.OCX"; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: regserver restartreplace sharedfile;
Source: "ui.swf"; DestDir: "{app}\ui\"; Flags: ignoreversion 
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyApplication"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp4.0.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyApplication"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp4.0.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp4.0.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,MyApplication}";
```

Comment: Bro, show your script snippet.

Comment: Please go through the script .Thanks

Comment: From a quick view I can't see anything wrong except that `Description` script property in `[run]` section is intended to use for caption of the *do you want to run the application now* check box on the wizard's finish page and it needs to have the `postinstall` flag specified, so I would try to remove it and keep there only the `Filename` property. Unfortunately I can't verify it at this time..

Comment: The application setup file created by Inno compiler works properly as well as successfully installing and running the application on my development machine, but once i brought into new machine it wont,this is the embarrassing thing that i stucked on.. thank you

Comment: This is very hard to answer. One thing is clear, you need to find out what is different on the new machine from your development one. What OS they are using, is it 32/64-bit OS, what are the user's (application) privileges (mostly if they are Vista up). Does your application require a working directory specified, are you trying to install it into the same directories ?

Comment: This application works only in 32bit OS machine.The installation wizard has the provision to select the directory and can install there.

Comment: if we replace the packaged exe(application.exe) with the build from the IDE then it works fine.The interesting part is that when we launch the application after installation the task manager doesnt show the exe ,i mean in process . thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to run the [RUN] section entry at the end of the setup script, add `Flags: postinstall` to the line.

Comment: Probably download a certain version of inno setup extractor for an exe to work it might work

Answer (score 0):

Change your `[Run]` section to the following:

```
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Where `#MyAppExeName` is the name of your `.exe` file.